# Windows 10 resolution keeps changing back to default

Tags: windows-10, resolution

Whenever I try to change my resolution on my PC away from the default resolution (1920x1080), after a few seconds it keeps changing back.
Still happens if I use the nvidia control panel to change resolution or the windows settings.
Any idea how to solve this?
This only started happening after I recently reformatted my pc, as I used to do this all the time.

OS: Windows 10
GPU: GTX 660

P.s. If your wondering why I want to change from default it is because I like to play games on different resolution in windowed borderless mode.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was caused by VibranceGUI, which is a small utility program that increases saturation in the graphics driver setting when certain games are running.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your GPU driver is continuously trying to recover the optimum resolution for your display (while you're not playing). I suggest you checking your Nvidia GeForce setting and look for something like that. If you found it, disable it.

Also in my experience, Nvidia drivers will automatically set the resolution to the optimally when you start the game which may be different for different games.

By the way, although it may not be relevant, your GPU is a bit old, maybe trying to udate that changes something.

Comment: yes, matrix displays like LCD and OLED can only display at their native resolution, any other resolutions will cause quality degradation

Comment: No such setting exists, and my gpu is fine thanks, has always worked for me and is powerful enough for what I run